# Batch scripting for installation of a software with some options

Tags: batch-file, install4j

I am using the below script to silently install a install4j application:

```
start "C:\Temp" /WAIT Installer.3-00-00.Windows.exe -q -dir %localdir%
```

However, this works perfectly but now i want to modify the script to have some option. For. eg. the default installation language option is English. User can choose any language to install when doing normal installation. With the above script the language is English only. Is there any option, by which I can give an option via command line for different language?

Thanks,
Kriti

Comment: Do this and see if you get any help...  Installer.3-00-00.Windows.exe /?

Comment: Also check the documentation to see if there is a language switch and then you can get input with `set /p` and set the language switch on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Batch doesn't have a built-in option parser like other languages, so you'll have to do it yourself, e.g. like this:

```
@echo off

setlocal

:continue
if "%1"=="" then goto finished
if /i "%1"=="/l" then (
  shift
  set "lang=%1"
) else if ... (
  ...
)
shift
goto continue
:finished

REM option parsing ends here, regular code below
```

---

**Edit:** If I understand the *install4j* documentation correctly, then you **must** use the options `-q -dir "C:\destination\folder"` for an [unattended install](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/helptopics/installers/installerModes.html), even if you provide a [response file](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/helptopics/installers/responseFile.html) via `-varfile "C:\path\to\your.varfile"`. The option `-c` would run the installer in console mode, which is different from unattended mode.

I'd try creating a response file `Installer.3-00-00.Windows.varfile` in the same folder as `Installer.3-00-00.Windows.exe` and then run the installer like this:

```
@echo off

setlocal

set "localdir=C:\destination\folder"

cd /d C:\installer\folder
start "Install" /wait Installer.3-00-00.Windows.exe -q -dir "%localdir%"
```

BTW, the first parameter of the `start` command sets the title of the console window. It doesn't change the working directory. If you want to set the working directory for the started program, you have to use `/d "C:\Temp"`:

```
start "Install" /d "C:\Temp" /wait Installer.3-00-00.Windows.exe -q -dir "%localdir%"
```

Comment: Thank you everyone with your prompt reply. Following suggestions by @RGuggisberg, I explored some more options. First I am doing a normal installation and getting a response file. Then I  am using this response file to perform a custom console installation. I am using the script start "C:\Temp" /WAIT Installer.3-00-00.Windows.exe -c -varfile response.varfile. The problem is it still shows that "This will install xxxx on your computer.
OK [o, Enter], Cancel [c] ". The question is now, why it is not reading from response file? and how to perform this custom console installation by using varfile

Comment: ***Before doing the console installation, I copied the response file from \.install4j\ to C:\Temp

Comment: @ Ansgar Wiechers: Thank again for your answer. I followed what you said but doesnt help in my case. I need to use -c and then automate the further responses. I thought of setting the variables through response file but no luck. start "C:\Temp\" /wait Installer.3-00-00.Windows.exe -c -dir %localdir% -varfile Installer.3-00-00.Windows.varfile. I guess may be the approach which I am taking is not correct. But Again, millions of thanks.

Comment: That's a lost cause I'd say. An install either is unattended or it is not. You can't have a "partially unattended install".

Answer (score 0):

You can set the language from the command line with the argument

```
-Dinstall4j.language=fr
```

(French in this case). The language must be one of those that are configured on the General settings->Languages step.

for changing other settings in the installer, consider using a [response file](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/helptopics/installers/responseFile.html). All response file variables can also be passed on the command line with the syntax `-VvariableName=value`.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply as well. Following ur approach and whatever suggested by http://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/, I tried some solution. As u know, langauge setting is not only my concern,there are various options during installation via console. I have to automate everything via batch scripting. so when I run this command start "C:\Temp\" /wait Installer.3-00-00.Windows.exe -c -dir %localdir% , I get the message in console "This will install xxxx" on your computer. Press Ok, Cancel. Now I need to program in my script to press Ok or Cancel.

Comment: And then many other things have to be set. Then I thought of using response file but this doesnt help as I believe not all variables can be set via response file. any suggestions to automate the user response will be appreciated or M I going in completely wrong direction?